# PHP Regex to allow only one decimal and one percentage sign

Tags: php, regex

Hello I'm trying to create a regex to validate a percentage value but I only want to allow one decimal after at least one digit and and one percentage sign as the last character. For example the following values below should be valid:

```
8%

10%

12.60%

7.750%
```

So far this is my regex code for my php function.

```
if(!preg_match('/[^0-9.%]/', $string)){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If I was going to guess, I'd say the downvotes were from the two other answers who provided reasonable answers then you told them that their pattern don't work for a particular input string (and they do).  I have gone to a greater length to explain how to use a pattern with php and explain the pattern syntax.  If you have questions, please leave me a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern: `/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?%$/`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/7mqiIJ/1

Explanation:

```
^            #start of the string
\d+          #match one or more digits
(?:          #start a non-capturing group
    \.\d+    #match one decimal point (dot) followed by one or more digits
)?           #make the group optional
%            #match one percent sign
$            #end of the string
```

You may want to fully consider any fringe cases that you want to validate as false.

Fringe Cases:

- `01%` (leading omittable zero)
- `.10%` (trailing omittable zero)

These cases may not be grounds for deeming a value as invalid, but probably could/should be trimmed of omittable zeros.  (This can be done as part of the `preg_match` call if you want to be clever about it.)

To omit leading zeros, you can use: `/^0*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?%$/` to match all leading `0`'s and then restart the fullstring match with `\K`.  The trailing zeros (just before `%`) will require a different approach -- but perhaps they don't bother you.

Here is how you can execute it: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/042a324b7c209730ea37a31c27d8abf0f0cf6fdb))

```
$string='10.99%';
if(preg_match('/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?%$/',$string)){
    echo 'valid';
} else {
    echo 'invalid';
}

echo "\n\n";

$string='10.%';
if(preg_match('/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?%$/',$string)){
    echo 'valid';
} else {
    echo 'invalid';
}
```

Output:

```
valid

invalid
```

Comment: Since you broke it down I'm giving you the credit I wish I could give all the answers some credit.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by making your regex more specific:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?%$
```

Try it out on regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/D9JN3e/3

Comment: This allows for more than one decimal and percentage sign.

Comment: It's been updated.  I mixed up teh ^ and $ for some reason and I made it support multiple decimals.  Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a counter example.  I removed your double negative code.  Remove the `!` in front of your `preg_match`.

Comment: all the answers where correct it was my localhost that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

This regex should be what you're looking for:

```
^[0-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9]+)?\%{1}$
```

all of the followings pass through this regex:

- 1%
- 1.5%
- 10%
- 10.5%
- 10.555%

Anything with two percent signs will fail, also mis-formatted expressions like `1.%` will fail.

Comment: As I said to nfn neil  This will validate with your code .300%.933

Comment: all the answers where correct it was my localhost that was the problem